# Why is Jersey requiring me to include a bean validation dependency in my project?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

EDIT: I'm using Jersey 2.22 and Hibernate 4.1.4.

According to the documentation:

> Bean Validation support in Jersey is provided as an **extension module** and needs to be mentioned explicitly in your pom.xml file (in case of using Maven)

As far as I can understand, it's not required. However, I'm using Hibernate as well in my project and this may be a huge factor.

Funny thing is that I don't use bean validation in my Hibernate, everything's old school configured in XML (mapping, persistence, session factory, etc).

This error comes up `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints` whenever I include the `validation-api-1.1.0-Final.jar`, which came from the Jersey bundle, as part of my dependencies.

The temporary fix I made is to disable `javax.persistence.validation.mode` in my Hibernate configuration and everything worked out alright. But the problem is, I don't want to touch my configuration anymore since this Hibernate project is used across all my projects and I fear that this small change might make a huge impact - paranoia I guess.

So I have two questions:

1. Why is Jersey requiring me to include a bean validation dependency? (requiring in the sense that if I don't have one, my app will keep throwing an exception)
2. Seeing that I don't use bean validations for Hibernate but intend to use bean validations in Jersey, am I better off disabling `javax.persistence.validation.mode`? or will it be best to just include a bean validation jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Jersey requiring me to include a bean validation dependency?
>   (requiring in the sense that if I don't have one, my app will keep
>   throwing an exception)

I don't know why it is required. If Bean Validation is truly optional, there should also be no dependency to the Bean Validation API. This might require some usage of reflection in the Jersey code. Maybe optional is meant in this case in a sense that you don't need an actual Bean Validation implementation. It would help if you could post the type of exception you get when you remove the Bean Validation API.

> Seeing that I don't use bean validations for Hibernate but intend to
>   use bean validations in Jersey, am I better off disabling
>   javax.persistence.validation.mode? or will it be best to just include
>   a bean validation jar?

Bean Validation integrates with JPA, meaning if you are using Hibernate ORM via an *EntityManager*, Bean Validation will be enabled if it is detected on the classpath. And the detection is via a class in the Bean Validation API jar. So, hence, if you add the Bean Validation API jar, you get Bean Validation enabled (even though there will be exceptions there as well until you also add a Bean Validation provider like Hibernate Validator). The way to disable JPA based validation in the case that you have the Bean Validation API on the classpath is indeed via the *javax.persistence.validation.mode* property.

So, if you want to use Bean Validation for validating on the REST level, you will need the Bean Validation API + an implementation (for example Hibernate Validator). Once you have these two things on the classpath and you don't want to have JPA life cycle based validation, you will need to set *javax.persistence.validation.mode* to *none* as well.

Comment: Thank you. I resulted to including a Hibernate Validator for my project!